# Sticky nav duplicating header background image and making it jump

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am experiencing an issue when I start scrolling down and reach the point when the sticky nav becomes visible, it seems to create a duplicate of the background from header and makes header jump, but it is supposed to move to the next section. Is it CSS or JS related issue?

Please see entire included code:

https://codepen.io/pipistrellonetopier/pen/yXLGjo

CSS code

```
.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
    z-index: 9999;
}

.sticky .main-nav { margin-top: 22px; }

.sticky .main-nav li a:link,
.sticky .main-nav li a:visited {
    padding: 14px 0;
    color: #f0f0f0;
    font-size: 100%;
}

.sticky .logo { 
    display: block;
    height: 29px;
    margin: 15px 0;
}
```

Thank you

Peter

Answer (score 0):

Give the following hyperlink `display:inline-block` and it will stop jumping:

```
<a href="#" target="_blank" class="app-store-btn"><img src="resources/css/img/app-store-btn.svg" alt="App Store Button"></a>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it remained the same. Do you have any other suggestions?